LaTeX symbols inside Expectation
I use LaTeX in my Mathematica code (using "^+4"), and was surprised that the first line in the code below evaluates correctly, but the second (essentially identical) line does not:
Expectation[v \[Conditioned] (v - a + ϵ - Subscript[θ, 2] q + 
     Subscript[θ, 2] r) == x, {v \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[OverBar[v], Subscript[σ, v]^2], ϵ \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[0, Subscript[σ, ϵ]^2], 
  q \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[OverBar[q], Subscript[σ, q]^2]}]

Expectation[v \[Conditioned] (v - a + ϵ - Subscript[θ, 2] q + 
     Subscript[θ, 2] OverBar[q]) == x, {v \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[OverBar[v], Subscript[σ, v]^2], ϵ \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[0, Subscript[σ, ϵ]^2], 
  q \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[OverBar[q], Subscript[σ, q]^2]}]


As can be seen, the only difference in the second line is that I use $\bar{q}$ instead of $r$. How come this causes the Expectation to no longer evaluate?
I just read that using sub- and superscripts is not recommended in Mathematica, but as can be seen, the first line also uses subscripts and evaluates correctly.
More generally, I'm wondering what recommendations people have for avoiding subscripts. Part of what makes Mathematica appealing to me is that I can easily read the LaTeXcode, and I can also copy the answers it returns directly into LaTeX. When using non-Latex code, it becomes much more cumbersome to do this. Finally, if sub- and superscripts are to be avoided, I wonder why there is a LaTeX option in the first place (for inline code)?

qbar appears twice in the second line?

Is that not allowed? qbar is supposed to be a constant

I am just saying that you are not just changing r into qbar

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! For your further questions, please always include a copy-pastable Mathematica code instead of a screenshot, so that others can easily reproduce the problem. (I have edited this question for you this time.) Now to your problem: I believe Mathematica is being confused because you have both $q$ and $\overline q$ in your expression ... For example, if you change $\overline q$ to $\overline z$, it will give you the result. So it doesn't seem like the presence of "bar" symbols is the problem, but the simultaneous appearance of $q$ and $\overline q$ ...

Does this answer your question? Solve with v9 (issues with Subscript, Overscript, Superscript etc) In this question, you can see the same problem happening with Solve. Please read through the answers therein, which give several possible workarounds.
